# Get all form parameters in a @BeanParam (JAX-RS, Jersey)

Tags: java, spring-boot, jersey, jax-rs

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to get all the form parameters in a class that is annotated with @BeanParam for a REST endpoint.

For example, I have an endpoint:

```
   public void Response get(@BeanParam MyBeanClass bean) {
       ...
   }
```

And I'd like to be able to get the Form parameters in `MyBeanClass`. I don't want to use `@FormParam` because that requires knowing what the parameters are ahead of time. I can't seem to figure out how to do this if it's even possible though. Is it?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to get form parameters using `@BeanParam` without `@FormParam`.

`@BeanParam` is simply a *parameter aggregator*. Besides `@FormParam`, it also supports `@QueryParam`, `@PathParam`, `@HeaderParam`, and even `@Context` annotations.

Offical docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/index.html?javax/ws/rs/BeanParam.html